# If myStr = 'test', why does myStr[4] produce error out of range but myStr[4:] does not?

Tags: python, recursion

I'm using recursion to iterate through the values of a string. When I get past the last character, it's allowing me to use that index position as an empty string `""` instead of giving an error. Why is that?

```
myStr = 'test'
print(myStr[4])
```

produces an error

```
print(myStr[4:])
```

does not produce any error.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Slicing is not bounds-checked by the built-in types. If the array indices are out of bounds, it will automatically truncate then at the right places.

Answer (score 0):

Because array accesses are defined such that it's an error for a lone index to be out of range, but not for (part or all of) a slice to be.  If any part of a slice is out of range, it simply yields no results, rather than triggering an error.

Answer (score -1):

Because that's how the language was designed. [Python 3.0 documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/introduction.html#strings) says about strings that

> Attempting to use an index that is too large will result in an error. However, **out of range *slice indexes* are handled gracefully when used for slicing**.

```
word = 'test'

>>> word[4]  # the word only has 4 characters
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
IndexError: string index out of range

>>> word[2:4]
'st'
>>> word[4:]
''
```